# Should I use SHA or OUR for sending an international wire to my stock broker's bank account?

Tags: international-transfer, fees, wire-transfer, swift

I am trying to send an international wire transfer to my US stock broker, TD Ameritrade. TD Ameritrade has asked me to send a wire to its bank account at First National Bank of Omaha. My local (non-US) bank has informed me that there will be one intermediary bank between it and First National Bank. There is no currency conversion involved as I am sending in US dollars.

Should I choose SHA or OUR when sending the wire? Is there a difference in costs if I am the ultimate beneficiary (i.e. I am both the sender and the recipient of the cash)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are both sender and receiver, use SHA. It's simple and easy, plus you will know who is charging more... In this specific case, First National shouldn't be charging anything as they would receive the funds over CHIPS network..
OUR for retail individuals works on approximation of charges and can be more or less.

Generally there are 4 bank's at times even 6 banks ...
SHA: Charges of Sender and Sender's Correspondent is borne by sender and receiver and receiver correspondent by beneficiary.
OUR: All the charge are borne by Sender.
BEN: All the charges are borne by Beneficiary and generally deducted from payment amount.

Comment: Is BEN the same as OUR in that the charges are approximate?

Comment: @Flux In BEN, the sender bank deducts it's fees and send the balance ahead, the sender correspondent deducts his fee and sends it ahead, like wise till beneficiary bank. So it's accurate.

Comment: How is this any different from SHA?